# The operation has timed out at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() while sending large number of requests to a host

Tags: c#, timeout, operation, getresponse

I am sending a large number of simultaneous requests to a particular web service with different data. To achieve this, I have created a number of threads(around 50 in number). Total number of requests per minute may increase up to 10000. 
The application in the form of a windows service runs fine for a few minutes and then a operation time out error is encountered.

I have tried the usual suspects such as increasing **DefaultConnectionLimit**, closing the web response object. Since the requests do not take much time on server, I have also set the request **Timeout** and **ReadWriteTimeout** to 5 seconds.
Below is the code snippet which is called repeatedly by different threads.

```
// Below line is executed at the start of application
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 15000;

// Below code is executed at repeatedly by different threads
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
request.Host = hostName;
request.Proxy = null;
request.UserAgent = "Windows Service";
byte[] bytes = new byte[0];
if (body != null)
{
    bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(body);
    request.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'";
    request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
}
request.Method = "POST";
request.Timeout = 5000;
request.ReadWriteTimeout = 5000;

request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(username + ":" + password));

request.CookieContainer = this.cookieContainer;

if (body != null)
{
    Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    requestStream.Close();
}

HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
     responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
httpResponse.Close();
```

Comment: Are you using http 1.0 or 1.1?  Try forcing to 1.0 : request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10; 1.1 is chunk mode and if you do not send next chunk message you will get a timout.

Comment: @FaizanRabbani : -yes I tried to increase timeout but it just slows down subsequent requests and the error is logged after that timeout period. So, isn't really helping us.

Comment: @FaizanRabbani :- No, its a windows service.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is on your side? Perhaps the web service only (for example) services 3 requests at a time and queues the others?

Comment: Can you try something this user suggested?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16744521/4222487

Comment: I am not sending 15000 requests simultaneously, But is there any issue with setting this value to 15000 instead of 50? It still is more than the number of simultaneous requests. I see no documentation which says so.

Comment: Does it improve if you set it to 50? Also please update your post to show how you are managing threading. Is it `Parallel.ForEach`? Something else?

Comment: No not yet......

Answer (score 5):

`ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit` limits the number of outgoing web requests to a given server. The default is generally [2 or 10](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appid=dev14idef1&l=en-us&k=k%28system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit%29%3Bk%28targetframeworkmoniker-.netframework,version%3Dv4.6.1%29%3Bk%28devlang-csharp%29&rd=true&f=255&mspperror=-2147217396#Anchor_2).

If you are making 50 parallel calls to that web service, you should set `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit` (at app startup) to a larger number (e.g. [40-50](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jpsanders/2009/05/20/understanding-maxservicepointidletime-and-defaultconnectionlimit/)).

*Additionally, you are not calling `Close` or `Dispose` on `request`. You should do this, or let [`using`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17357258/does-using-statement-always-dispose-the-object) take care of it for you.*

Comment: So, when you make more simultaneous request than the DefaultConnectionLimit , aren't requests just queued? Could you lose a request this way?

Comment: Yes they are queued @HenkHolterman. But if you queue **enough** of them, some will start to timeout (as the OP mentions). Imagine doing 10,000 requests a minute, and each request takes 10 seconds. If you do only 10 requests at a time (default value of this setting for a web app), clearly your throughput is _effectively_ capped to 60 per minute. 9,940 of them will timeout.