# API Exception randomly : A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, bing-api

I have hosted my application in prod server. This application will hit the Bing map concurrently to bring the location based response. This application is used to send N number of location as API request to get the API response in order to process the location data.

API : "https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations"

And its working fine but randomly getting following exception, which impacts the application consistent.

**API Call**

```
private async Task<BingResponse> GetBingResponse(string argUri)
{
    try
    {
        WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(argUri));
        var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();

        if (((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            using (Stream resStream = (response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                DataContractJsonSerializer jsonData = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(BingResponse));
                return jsonData.ReadObject(resStream) as BingResponse;
            }
        }
        else
            return null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        XLLogger.Write("Exception with BingResponse URL");
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Exception**

```
{
    "ClassName": "System.Net.WebException",
    "Message": "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. (dev.virtualearth.net:443)",
    "Data": null,
    "InnerException": {
        "StatusCode": null,
        "Message": "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. (dev.virtualearth.net:443)",
        "Data": {},
        "InnerException": {
            "ClassName": "System.Net.Sockets.SocketException",
            "Message": "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.",
            "Data": null,
            "InnerException": null,
            "HelpURL": null,
            "StackTraceString": "   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token)\r\n   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.<ConnectAsync>g__WaitForConnectWithCancellation|277_0(AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs saea, ValueTask connectTask, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClass216_0.<<CreateHttpClient>b__1>d.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location ---\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectToTcpHostAsync(String host, Int32 port, HttpRequestMessage initialRequest, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)",
            "RemoteStackTraceString": null,
            "RemoteStackIndex": 0,
            "ExceptionMethod": null,
            "HResult": -2147467259,
            "Source": "System.Net.Sockets",
            "WatsonBuckets": null,
            "NativeErrorCode": 10060
        },
        "HelpLink": null,
        "Source": "System.Net.Http",
        "HResult": -2147467259,
        "StackTrace": "   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectToTcpHostAsync(String host, Int32 port, HttpRequestMessage initialRequest, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.AddHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation`1.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SendRequest(Boolean async)\r\n   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)"
    },
    "HelpURL": null,
    "StackTraceString": "   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location ---\r\n",
    "RemoteStackTraceString": null,
    "RemoteStackIndex": 0,
    "ExceptionMethod": null,
    "HResult": -2147467259,
    "Source": "System.Net.Requests",
    "WatsonBuckets": null
}
```

Comment: i would check how much connections is created to a host `dev.virtualearth.net:443`. And highly likely would replace `HttpWebRequest.Create` with `HttpClient`

Comment: Consider using [HttpClientFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests) to make these http requests

Comment: @Ryan I was using `HttpClient` in first place but there was same error that's why tried changing `HttpWebRequest`

Comment: I am not sure how `HttpWebRequest.Create` works with TCP-connections internally, but if u work with the single host, which doesn't change its IP-address often, it is recommended to use single long-lived HttpClient. Once established, its TCP-connection could be reused then for a long time (depends on PooledConnectionLifetime value of Handler). If then error is reproduced, then probably problem on the Bing side.

Comment: Hi did you had the chance to take a look into the error log or stacktrace in which scenario does it encountered the error? Do you have any other environment like UAT or Test Or Dev test? What I am pointing is, does the same error reprodudible in other environemt?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron I can able to reproduce in all environments except Local and here problem is randomly occurring, The same request is working fine but at some point its not working. Also we had load balancer in hosting environment

Answer (score -1):

For your **WSAETIMEDOUT** **10060** error, Try these solutions.

1. Set the Timeout and ReadWriteTimeout for HttpWebRequest.

[Adjusting HttpWebRequest Connection Timeout in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500955/adjusting-httpwebrequest-connection-timeout-in-c-sharp)

2. HttpWebResponse code in using block.

[HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() keeps getting timed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16744432/httpwebrequest-getresponse-keeps-getting-timed-out)